# iPad JavaScript - Occasional long delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari

Some of my website's JavaScript is heavily delayed on an iPad. The delayed JavaScript is simple. It is just displaying or hiding a particular area.

JavaScript:

```
function showbox(box) {
    $(box).show('blind');
}

function hidebox(box) {
    $(box).hide('blind');
}

function togglearea(area) {
    if ($(area).is(":visible")) {
        hidebox(area);
    }
    else{
        showbox(area);
    }   
}
```

This called from an 'OnClick' 
EG. onclick="togglearea('#areatotoggle')"

I haven't had a problem using a desktop, but occasionally there is an issue on an iPad. The delay is over 10 seconds.

Should I be doing this differently? Why should this create such a delay?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it slow every time you call the function, or just the first time? If the first time, it sounds like a slow JIT compiler.

Comment: Sometimes I load the page and it works perfectly. Other times I load the page and it is slow on every function call. IE. When it works the first time, it works every time. When it doesn't work properly the first time, it continues to not work properly

Comment: i doubt the problem lies in the code shown. since js is single-threaded, a buys background interval or IO can slow down all other code quite a bit. it's just that you might only notice the slowdown on those calls.

Comment: So I suppose if that is the case then there's nothing I can do